# Animating content between constraints

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this element in compose which I want to animate so that if another element changes, it moves from the end of the constraint to the start of it. I've tried setting the horizontal bias with animatable but it does not seem to work, it's like it takes the offset and it barely moves. I also tried passing the value as it's shown here with BiasAlignment.Horizontal, but no luck. Is there a correct way to do this?

```
@Composable
private fun animateHorizontalAlignmentAsState(
    targetBiasValue: Float
): State<BiasAlignment.Horizontal> {
    val bias by animateFloatAsState(targetBiasValue)
    return derivedStateOf { BiasAlignment.Horizontal(bias) }
}

var horizontalBias by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }

val alignment by animateHorizontalAlignmentAsState(
     targetBiasValue = horizontalBias
)

LaunchedEffect(elementFace) {
    horizontalBias = if (elementFace == ElementFace.Front) 1f else -1f
}

Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(40.dp)
                .constrainAs(flipLabel) {
                    linkTo(
                        start = parent.start,
                        end = parent.end
                        // I was using it here for the horizontalBias, does not seem to work
                    )
                }
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        )
        {
           Icon(
                 modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp),
                 painter = painterResource(id = "repleat"),
                 contentDescription = null
          )
}
```